# How to put original input into dyanmic dropdown list

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a question to ask. Apparently for my website, i am doing a updating of data and for that, i am using a dropdown list to make a certain update, however, i do not know how to put the original input into the dynamic dropdown list, thus i might need to put the original and a new one together, which can be a bit confusing for the user if they do not wish to make any changes there. I shall screenshot below so that you can understand better.

```
echo "Old Branch";
echo ": " . "<input type = 'text' style = 'width: 200px' name ='branchno' value = '$sbranch_name' required readonly>";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "New Branch: ";
$mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$sql="Select sbranch_name from branches";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<select name='sbranch_name'>";
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<option value='" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "'>" . $row['sbranch_name'] . "</option>";
  }
  echo "</select>";
}  
$mysqli->close();
```

[Old input in text and new input in dropdown list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpLsS.png)

Edited codes:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli(spf, dbuser, dbpw, db);
$sql="Select sbranch_name from branches";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$data= array();     
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $data[] = $row['sbranch_name'];
        }
            $data[] = $sbranch_name;
        echo "<select name='sbranch_name'>";
        foreach($data as $branch)
        {
            echo "<option value='" .$branch . "'>" . $branch. "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select'>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly add data from DB to array

```
$data= array();     
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$data[] = $row['sbranch_name'];
}
```

Then jus add data to that array, add your original branch:

```
$data[] = $sbranch_name;
```

And make foreach loop to display new select list.

```
echo "<select name='sbranch_name'>";
foreach($data as $branch){
echo "<option value='" .$branch . "'>" . $branch. "</option>";
}
echo "</select'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select>
     //loop through the option
      <option value="test" <?= $original=="test"?"selected">Audi</option>
    </select>
```

The concept is to echo 'selected' if the value of the option matches with the $original which is saved in the database previously.

You can replace the above "test" with what you did previously. The only thing you need to add is to retrieve the previously stored value from database to $original and use the concept.

For example, when selected is appended inside option, it selects that value for default.

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

If you didn't get what I'm sharing, I can explain to you more with your code.